# How to render JSX by calling a regular function instead of a React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, rendering

I tried adding 'return' before the JSX, but it stops the iteration. How can I write this correctly?

```
function App(){

  function foo(obj){
    for(let key in obj) {
      <div>...</div>
    }
  }

  return {
    <>
      {foo({...})}
    </>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `return` the JSX; it can't just be lying around in the function. Something like this should do the trick:

```js
function App(){

  function recursion(object){
    const ret = [];

    for(let key in object){
      if(typeof object[key] === 'object'){
        ret.push (
          <>
            <div>{key}</div>
            {recursion(object[key])}
          </>
        );
      } else {
        ret.push(<div>{key}</div>);
      }
    }

    return ret;
  }

  return (
    <>
      {recursion(someObject)}
    </>
  );
}
```